# Apps Script send a whole sheet via the MailApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know how I can send a message that is only one cell. How can I send a whole sheet or lets say A1:J30 ? Is it possible to make it look like you copy pasted it out of the sheet?

Comment: Send it as csv.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to send the whole document, you can extract the range you need and then create a [new document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document?hl=en), insert the range you want to share, save it in a drive account, and then share the link.

If you want the range into a string you can use:

```
newString = yourArray.join(" ");
```